# dlookup or dsum not working with date as field name

Tags: ms-access, vba

Please help. I have written an access program, and I have used dates as field names, or column heading in the table.
Now when I try to use DSUM or DLOOKUP, it does not behave correctly at all.

If I change the table name to random text, it works.
Please help me with this....

```
DLookUp("08/15/2015","qp_data2","Discipline = 'CSA'")
```

does not work, but

```
DLookUp("test","qp_data2","Discipline = 'CSA'")
```

does

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue using square brackets:

```
DLookUp("[08/15/2015]","qp_data2","Discipline = 'CSA'")
```